# How to group selected multiple rows in one in React-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, frontend

I am using React-Table by https://react-table.tanstack.com/. and I want to add functionality as iif I select 2-3 rows and click on an icon, say "Group"... then those selected row will merge in one with an expand icon... when I click to expand, then it will show all selected row in expansion

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wind-3sysg?file=/src/components/EnhancedTable.js

Comment: the useCase is : when you select multiple rows you want it to be render in a dropdown menu in a table row even if they are not one after the other?
I'm right?

Comment: @antoineso I mean... if I select 2-3 rows and click on an icon, say "Group"... then those selected row will merge in one with an expand icon... when I click to expand, then it will show all selected row in expansion